# Including an external library in Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm new to visual studio and can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

I'm working on a project in VC++ with VS2010. I have another project that builds into a .lib file set up as a reference, but can't figure out how to actually include the headers. Google has proved useless. Please help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally this is done by adding the directory where the include files live to the project's "Additional Include Directories" property (in the "C/C++ | General" property page).

Note that the location can be a relative path if the different projects will always be at the same file system level relative to one another, or they can use VS macros or environment variables.