# Error C3861: fips_aes_cbc_encrypt: identifier not found

Tags: c, windows, openssl, fips

I compile program using openSSL and during compilation I am getting:

error `C3861: fips_aes_cbc_encrypt: identifier not found`

and functions AES_cbc_encrypt marked with red underline.

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: What was the program you compiled? What compiler did you use, on what platform?  Did you include the right libraries during your compilation? It would be good to show your exact compilation command used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894013/how-to-use-openssl-in-gcc for some possible suggestions.

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2012 (win7). and i'm trying to compile openRTMFP cumulus server (https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus/wiki/Installation#windows-build). **"It would be good to show your exact compilation command used"** - i just push compile button and it all starts...

Comment: but in instructions for installation is said **"Visual Studio 2008/2010 solution and project files are included. It searchs external librairies in External/lib folder and external includes in External/include folder in the root Cumulus folder. So you must put POCO, OpenSSL and LuaJIT headers and libraries in these folders."** i tryed to do as it said but i'm failed. so all what i could do is manually take folders compiler was asking and put them into "include" folder of existing cumulus project.

Comment: You need to find the OpenSSL _libraries_ and put them in the libraries folder - that is different than the include files. Libraries are pre-compiled "bits of code that someone else wrote". They need to end up in `External/lib` . Can you show what is in that directory?

Comment: well if i know how to show you... i'll try to explain. this is what kind of directory tree i have now: **camulus-master** contais **camulus-master** contais **cumulusLib and cumulusServer**. **cumulusLib** contains **include, lib, sources, tmp** and some other files. what i did is put into include folder everything what i found inside **openssl/include**

Comment: i tryed to create External/lib, External/include inside root, inside cumulusLib/include and put openssl inside but none worked. so when i put in into cumulusLib/include and everything started to work i thought it is the right decision...

Comment: Randomly creating directories until something works is probably not the answer. I don't have Visual Studio, but I think that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789927/including-an-external-library-in-visual-studio-2010-project might show you "the right way". It explicitly tells how to add the include file - I have to believe something very similar allows you to add the library file.

Comment: ok. it seems it's done. compiled without errors. however i did it randomly without understanding what i was doing. anyway thanks for your help guys!